# WebRTC sending string messages

Tags: javascript, html, text, webrtc

I want to realize a simple application in HTML/Javascript.

There should be two pages:

page1.html and page2.html. page1 should have a text box and a button. When pressing the button it should just be sent to page2, which has to display it.

I have found this example and hosted :

http://bobvann.noip.me/temp/chatp2p/

(this works with a websocket which connects to a ruby program running on that same server.

Please let me have a simple solution how to send text messages from a page to an other. Just this.

Thank you very much.

Have a good day :)

Comment: Do you realize that this still requires some server-side software, namely the signaling server? WebRTC is peer-to-peer, but each client has to find other peers, and just broadcasting and listening doesn't quite work.

Comment: Yes, I have no problem in running any server-side software. I have a server and can run whatever I want. What I need to do is pratically writing on my smartphone and having in real-time the message displayed on my desktop. No matter of what technologies should I use. I just thought WebRTC would be fine. In the link I previously posted there is an example which I found on the net on a video-chat between two users using webRTC and a websocket server. Now I think it would be possible to edit it a bit and use for texting. Thanks BR

Answer (score 4):

So assuming you know how to set up WebRTC for audio and video, the answer is quite short. You need to use a WebRTC **data channel** over a similar "peer connection" that is used for audio and video. [Here](http://simpl.info/rtcdatachannel/) is a decent example that shows how to send strings. You should be able to use it for sending structured messages in JSON, major browsers have `JSON.parse` that deals with conversion to objects.

But you probably want to know how it works in a bit more detail than a working non-configurable example, even if it solves your problem. Some up-to-date explaination about what it is and how to use it can be found in [this article on HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/datachannels/). The nature of your task implies using a reliable mode — you don't want your messages have a chance of not arriving or arriving disordered, right? The rest is up to you.

Regardless, I strongly recommend that you watch and understand [this presentation about WebRTC at Google I/O](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/326336563) that show pretty much everything WebRTC is designed for.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript and PHP connected through AJAX is far from enough to achieve a chat.

Each side you need:
a DIV to display the conversation.
Followed:
an INPUT to enter message.
a BUTTON to send your message, using an Ajax function
that send string.

A PHP function to append the message field at the end of a chat sequential text file, display back chat list in the DIV.

Trick if you send an empty message, jump append, it will display your counterpart messages had sent while.
Empty message can trigger BUTTON after 5 sec delay repeatedly.